# C++ Using Object with pass function

Tags: c++, object

I'm trying to build a object with other object and pass the function

---

Sorry for unclear description
the question is if the **TESTobj** is someone else object, and I build the new object(**Gradebook**) and use **TESTobj** to pass the function, pass the function without the object is no problem but in the object will error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘TESTobj::SET(void (GradeBook::*)())’

no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void (GradeBook::*)()’ to ‘void (*)()’
```

Here is Example:

```
void TESTobj::SET(void (*nu)())
{//point the function
    this->nu=nu;
}

void TESTobj::Test()
{//implement the function
    (*nu)();
}

void GradeBook::Grade()
    {//the function I build
        cout << "HELLO" <<endl;
    }
void GradeBook::Set()
    {
        OBJ.SET(&GradeBook::Grade);//GotProblemHere
        OBJ.Test();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GradeBook::Grade` is a non-static member function, it needs to operate on an instance of `GradeBook`. You can't pass it in to a function expecting a plain function pointer.

You could change `TESTobj::SET` to accept `std::function` objects, then wrap your member function in a lambda:

```
void TESTobj::SET(std::function<void()> nu)

void GradeBook::Set()
{
    OBJ.SET([this](){Grade();});
    OBJ.Test();
}
```